# Can Jenkins use restart hook?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

we have massive deployment of Jenkins with hundreds of jobs. We usually don't have time for **safe-restart**, we use **restart** instead. During restart, all jobs which were running are marked as failed. I would like to use restart Jenkins hook, so I could mark all those jobs as aborted.

There is possibility to write [init](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Hook+Script) hook, but I'm not sure about restart hook.

Is there a possibility to build such restart hook?

Answer (score 2):

Why reinvent the wheel? **[There is a plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Backup+and+interrupt+running+job+plugin)** that allows to reschedule all interrupted jobs for a restart